# Ordering a JPA Repository response by the first item in a referenced Entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, eclipselink, jpql

I have these JPA entities (simplified):

```
@Entity
class Trip {
    @Id
    Long tripId;

    String travelerName;

    @OneToMany
    List<TripLeg> tripLegs;
}

@Entity
class TripLeg {
    @Id
    Long tripLegId;

    Calendar departureDate;

    @ManyToOne
    Trip trip;
}
```

and this repository:

```
interface TripRepository extends JpaRepository<Trip, Long> {
    Page<Trip> findByTravelerName(String travelerName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Is there any way to sort that Page response by the earliest departure date among a trip's legs? Either via query methods or JPQL, or in the Pageable's sort properties?

So for instance, this Trip:

```
{
    id : 1,
    travelerName : "John Doe",
    tripLegs : [{
        id : 3,
        departureDate : 2015-10-03
    }]
}
```

would sort after this one:

```
{
    id : 2,
    travelerName : "John Doe",
    tripLegs : [{
            id : 1,
            departureDate : 2015-10-01
        }, {
            id : 2,
            departureDate : 2015-10-05
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your findByTravelerName method to do that

```
Page<Trip> findByTravelerNameOrderByTripLegsDepartureDateAsc(String travelerName, Pageable pageable);
```

Or try this query

```
SELECT trip FROM Trip as trip join trip.tripLegs as tleg group by tleg.trip_id order by tleg.departureDate ASC
```

Comment: That adds duplicate records in the page for each TripLeg -- IE, the result page goes from 2 Trips to 3 (one for each TripLeg we're sorting by).

Comment: Sam Jones updated the answer with query, but please first test it or try to convert it into sql

Answer (score 0):

You might try a subquery to find the minimum departurDate for a trip, and then use that as a filter on the trip.tripLegs

Something like

> "SELECT Distinct trip FROM Trip trip LEFT JOIN trip.tripLegs legs
>   WHERE legs.departureDate = (SELECT Min(l.departureDate) FROM TripLeg l
>   WHEREl.trip = trip) ORDER BY legs.departureDate"

Answer (score 0):

Someone I was discussing this with pointed out a blindingly obvious possibility -- just make a view. So that's what I ended up doing. I had tunnel-vision from focusing too much on the JPA solution that I didn't see the alternative that made sense.